# Making a link image rotates 90deg using css

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I am making my first steps learning to code. I've been taking some courses on Internet and now I decided to continue learning from the experience while I build a Wordpres theme.

The thing is that I made a 91 deg "y" rotated image that turns to 0 deg when I click it and then it can go back to 91 deg when I click outside:

```css
img {
    
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transform: rotatey(91deg);
}

.crossRotate {
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

.crossRotate:focus {
  transform: rotatey(0deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="crossRotate" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/03/29/01/54/tree-696839_960_720.jpg" tabindex="1" />
```

Basically what I want to achieve with all of this is to have a 91deg rotated image, when I click it, it turns to 0deg, then if I click into the the image again it will link me to another page, and if I click outside the image it will turn to 91 deg again.

I've been trying this since some days ago and this one is my best approach:

```css
img {
    
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transform: rotatey(91deg);
}

.crossRotate {
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

.crossRotate:focus {
  transform: rotatey(0deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.fr">
 
  <img class="crossRotate" src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FF0000.png" tabindex="1" />

</a>
```

Here I have an image with a tranformation and with a link to another page. It doesn't work because there is a conflict between the click to make it turn and the click to link to another page.

What I need is to make the click to turn the image first, and then when it is already turned make the click to go to the link. If I don't want to go to the link I can close the image again clicking outside the image.

Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: You'll need javascript for "clicks".

Comment: Do you some reference that I can see to learn how to do it?

Comment: Plenty of tutorials on the internet for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you want a two-phase button. On the first click the image rotates into view, on the second click it should activate a link. This is rather tricky except you use JavaScript. In the code below I re-used your trick with tabindex. I made a container focusable and used its focus state for both rotation of the image AND the displaying of a link. I used the anchors visibility setting in addition to rotation so that the link is not clickable when folded.

```css
.crossRotate {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

img {
    
    display: block;
    transform: rotatey(91deg);
}

.crossRotate img, .crossRotate a {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.crossRotate:focus img {
  transform: rotatey(0deg);
}

.crossRotate a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotatey(91deg);
}
.crossRotate:focus a, .corssRotate a:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotatey(0deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="crossRotate" tabindex="1">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/03/29/01/54/tree-696839_960_720.jpg" />
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</label>
```

**Explanation:**

An anchor element is basically only a rectangle. You can hide/show and rotate it the same way you can do with any other element. The OP used the focus state of the image to rotate it. I've moved the focus state to a common parent container and made both the image and the link behave differently based on that parent's focus state. Since the anchor is transparent and hidden by default, it's not clickable. As soon as the container is clicked, the image rotates to its full width. The same happens with the anchor. Additionally its visibility is switched to visible, so that it's actually clickable. Since the position of the parent container is relative, it's used as reference point for the absolute-positioned anchor. It's perfectly aligned on top of the image and thus has the same clickable area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hubert I see that it's a good idea to use tabindex. The thing is that it doesn't open the hyperlink it only closes again the image

Comment: Oh, right. Fixed that. I didn't see the problem of the link stealing the focus on click and therefore disabling itself. Should work now.

Comment: Just noticed it still has a minor bug: if you click anywhere beside the folded image, it expands too. That can be probably worked around, though. I'm leaving this up to you :-)

Comment: @Hubert Grzeskowiak, this looks like an elegant fix but how does it work without JavaScript, i mean avoiding the default behavior of the link? please explain

Comment: added explanation to the answer